# Initialize/import submodules without polluting the global namespace

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, python-import

Typically when I import modules, I prefer to just import the top module and treat everything as a member of that, rather than importing each function I need into the global namespace, ie:

```
import os
os.walk()
```

instead of:

```
from os import walk
walk()
```

However, I recently came across modules that have submodules that seemingly have to be imported globally in order to run. For example, the Scikit-Learn module contains the "cluster" submodule. I want to do this:

```
import sklearn as skl
skl.cluster.KMeans(...)
```

but this throws an error because I didn't initialize `sklearn.cluster`. Instead I have seen this:

```
from sklearn import cluster
cluster.KMeans(...)
```

I really don't like this because I don't like polluting my global namespace. Is there any way around this? I tried this:

```
import sklearn as skl
import skl.cluster
```

but that doesn't work either. How can I initialize a submodule without importing it globally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import sklearn as skl
import sklearn.cluster
```

The name after the `import` has to be the actual name of the module, not an alias. This does mean that you will end up with the `sklearn` name as well as the `skl` name bound to the `sklearn` module object.

There is no import that will initialize `sklearn.cluster` *and* bind the `skl` name to the `sklearn` module. The closest you can do is `del sklearn` after importing the submodules, or shove the submodule initialization imports somewhere where they won't bind names in this namespace, like a dedicated function or module or something (but hiding imports like that has its own issues), or use `importlib.import_module` to load the submodules.